# Symfony 2.8 injecting RequestStack error

Tags: symfony

I have problem with injecting RequestStack.

In this case, if I use just Request, everything is fine:

```
<?php

namespace Cms\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...
class DefaultController extends BaseController {
    public function mainAction(Request $request) {
...
```

But if I try to use RequestStack, I get error 
*"Controller "Cms\AdminBundle\Controller\DefaultController::mainAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$requestStack" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one)."*

Here is the code:

```
namespace Cms\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

...
class DefaultController extends BaseController {
    public function mainAction(RequestStack $requestStack) {
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `Symfony` docs:

> In a controller for instance, don't inject the request stack, use the Request type-hint on an action method argument instead.

`RequestStack` is a service but `Request` is a value object (not a service) not accessible from the container.

So if you need `request_stack` in you controller, depending on your constoller dependecies you can get it from container:

`$requestStack = $this->get('request_stack');`

or just inject it into controller constructor (if your controller is a service).